# Unit testing with Time Zone offset

Tags: angular, unit-testing, momentjs, karma-jasmine, angular-moment

I have worked with function in angular 5 using moment:

```
moment('2013-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').utcOffset('America/Los_Angeles')
    .startOf('Day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ')
```

When I test it in my local it's giving a proper response which I am expecting i.e. `-0800` time offset.

When we build it in deploying it's throwing error expected +0000 instead of -0800.

Can anyone help me out how to test this function?

Comment: I reckon that your server you deploy the software on has another time zone setup. You could find out whether this is true and then let both results +0000 and -0500 be true.

Comment: Don't mind Can you please be clear, If my software and server has diff time zones what should I be doing and. If they are still on same time zone then next what should I be doing to my code?

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand [from the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/), `utcOffset` does **not** work with timezones names such as "America/Los_Angeles". For that, you must use [moment.timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/):

```
moment.tz('2013-12-01', 'America/Los_Angeles')
    .startOf('Day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ') // 2013-12-01 00:00:00-08:00
```

Your code might work sometimes because, when you pass a string that's not recognizable, it uses the offset from the browser/environment timezone - so it doesn't matter if you call `utcOffset('America/Los_Angeles')` or `utcOffset('whatever')`, it'll use your browser/environment's timezone, and sometimes it'll work, sometimes not, depending on how the browser/environment is configured.